# Словообразование слова «различие»

Tags: словообразование

На сайте [Oshibok-Net.ru](http://www.oshibok-net.ru/) пишут, что слово **различие** образовано от глагола "различать" при помощи суффикса *-иj-.* Далее пишут: "...вначале приставка *раз-* присоединилась к основе существительного *лик* (в древности *ликъ*) одновременно с древним суффиксом существительного *-j-* (этот суффикс преобразовал звук К в Ч, т. е. современный звук Ч возник на месте древнего сочетания 2-х звуков — к и j), в результате было создано древнее существительное *различь* («различие»); затем на базе существительного *различь* при помощи суффикса было создано прилагательное *различный*".

Т. е. вначале образовалось слово "различие", и на его базе — производные слова.

Каким образом сегодня слово **различие** образуется от глагола? Если, например, произошли какие-нибудь исторические изменения, производное слово исчезло бы, тогда было бы понятней. Но в данном случае исторически оно само является производящим.

P. S. На мой вопрос, как так получилось, ответили: "Следует различать историческое и современное словообразование". (Отвечают профессиональные лингвисты.)

Comment: Хороший вопрос, хороший ответ — «что ещё надо человеку?..»

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Я искренне **похвалила** (и оценила, соответственно)  и Ваш вопрос, и ответ Людмилы. Просто я люблю "Белое солнце пустыни". _Хорошая жена, хороший дом — что ещё надо человеку, чтобы встретить старость?_ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v649bLQil4)

Comment: А-а, понятно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Профессиональные лингвисты абсолютно правы. Образование слов изучается и с современной точки зрения (как соотносятся в современном русском языке однокоренные слова, **идёт анализ семантики**), и с исторической (**когда и каким способом** было образовано то или иное слово). Результаты этих разных подходов к словообразованию могут различаться.

В лингвистике различают синхронное и диахроническое словообразование. **Диахроническое словообразование изучает реальные процессы образования одних языковых знаков от других на протяжении исторического развития языка, а также исторические изменения словообразовательной структуры отдельных слов (в частности, путем опрощения и переразложения). Синхронное словообразование изучает не столько процессы, сколько отношения между словами, сосуществующими в одном синхронном срезе языка.**

Так, русское слово *зонтик* с синхронной точки зрения является производным от слова *зонт*. Оно образовано с помощью присоединения к последнему суффикса -ик со значением уменьшительности. Однако реальная **историческая последовательность** появления этих слов в русском языке иная. Сначала из нидерландского языка было заимствовано слово *зонтик* (нидерл. zonnedek). Затем произошло переразложение, т.е. перемещение границы морфем внутри слова (в данном случае - ее возникновение). Заключительная часть корня –ик под влиянием аналогии (*домик, столик и т.д*.) стала восприниматься как самостоятельная морфема - уменьшительный суффикс. Вследствие этого возникло слово без уменьшительного суффикса - *зонт*. Таким образом, с синхронной точки зрения, можно говорить о следующем направлении словообразования: *зонт - зонтик*, а с диахронной - об обратном: *зонтик -зонт.*

С исторической точки зрения, глагол *забыть* является производным от глагола *быть*, однако с синхронной точки зрения это не так. В современном русском языке эти слова вообще не воспринимаются как однокоренные, а основа глагола *забыть* не членится на корень и приставку.

*Облако* в современном русском языке является словом с непроизводной (далее нечленимой, т. е. равной корню) основой облак-. В истории языка было не так: это слово некогда соотносилось с корнем влак-1волок- (ср. *волочить, волоку)*. Значит, в основе этого слова прежде выделялась приставка об- и корень влак-. Происходящий в языке исторический процесс уничтожения морфемных границ в слове и слияние двух или нескольких морфем в одну называется опрощением.

Современное словообразование не устанавливает прежних морфемных границ в слове, не изучает его историю (это задача исторического языкознания и особой науки о происхождении слов — этимологии), а принимает во внимание только те морфемы, которые устанавливаются на основании изучения связей между словами современного русского языка.

```
    Т. е. вначале образовалось слово "различие" и на его базе
     производные слова.
```

Нет, не так.

Словообразовательный анализ слова ***различие*** по Тихонову:

*Различие -  это существительное по глаголу различить*. Цепочка: различить - различ/-и[j- э] - суффиксальный способ.

Полная цепочка: раз/лич/и/ть - различ/-и[j-/ э] - различ/н(ый) - различн/о

Исторически (по этимологическому словарю Цыганенко):

лик- разлик - (различь)-различный;

лик- разлик - (различь)- различить - различие.

Т.е. исторически *различный* и *различить* образовались от *различь*.

Comment: Людмила, а как назвать такой способ словообразования?

Comment: Суффиксальный в обоих случаях: различ/н/(ый), различ/и(е ) (-и[j- / э]

Comment: Я не это имел в виду. Есть опрощение, диффузия,декорреляция, переразложение. К какому типу относится наш пример? Может, декорреляция?

Comment: Это не способы словообразования, это изменения в морфологическом составе слова в процессе исторического словообразования. У нас изменений характера морфем нет (лик-разлик-различить-различие приставка сохранилась, потому что различить-отличить), посмотрим, изменился ли корень: ликь, лико -"сходство", "мета","лицо", диалектное личить - метить, делать изображение похожим, различить - чем-то отметить, распознать среди других. Тоже не изменилось. Выходит, что корень тот же.

Comment: Просто мы забыли первоначальное значение слова лик - узнаваемое изображение, мета. Лик на иконе, например, - это точное изображение, а было  и прилагательное лик - схожий.Лицо - образ с отличительными чертами кого-то. А вот соотношение морфем - да, теперь мы не считаем, что различить произошло от "лик", теперь нет слов личить (хотя есть "не личит тебе = не к лицу"), различь, видимо, о декорреляции говорить возможно.